# Error deploying same app to multiple Firebase-projects

Tags: firebase, bitbucket

I'm trying to deploy the same app to multiple Firebase-projects but when i try to deploy it fails:

*Deploy target 1 not configured for project project-1. Configure with:

firebase target: apply hosting 1 <resources...>
Deployment failed.*

I have this configuration in my .firebaserc:

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "project-1": {
                "hosting": {
                    "1": [
                        "project-1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "project-2": {
                "hosting": {
                    "2": [
                        "project-2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "projects": {
        "1": "project-1",
        "2": "project-2"
    }
}
```

And my firebase.json:

```
{
    "hosting": [
        {
            "target": "1",
            "public": "dist/angular",
            "ignore": [
                "firebase.json",
                "**/.*",
                "**/node_modules/**"
            ],
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "destination": "/index.html"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "target": "2",
            "public": "dist/angular",
            "ignore": [
                "firebase.json",
                "**/.*",
                "**/node_modules/**"
            ],
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "destination": "/index.html"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I don't think this is possible

Comment: " firebase target:apply hosting project_name target_hosting_name"

Run this on command this will switch between hosting . then run deploy command